# Why does the canceled shipping amount not contain the taxes?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, tax, shipping-tax

I have an order where the net shipping amount is 5.00 CHF. 7.7% VAT are added to them so that the `shipping_incl_tax` is 5.39 CHF.

When I cancel an order in the administration panel the order's data regarding the shipping looks like that:

```
[shipping_amount]                           string  "5.0000"    
[shipping_canceled]                         float   5   
[shipping_description]                      string  "Flat Rate - Fixed" 
[shipping_discount_amount]                  string  "0.0000"    
[shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount] string  "0.0000"    
[shipping_incl_tax]                         string  "5.3900"    
[shipping_method]                           string  "flatrate_flatrate" 
[shipping_tax_amount]                       string  "0.3900"    
[state]                                     string  "canceled"
```

I am missing something like `shipping_tax_canceled` or something similar to know exactly how much of the shipping *and* the shipping taxes* was canceled or refunded.

Do you now if there is another place where i can find that information?

**Update:**
Maybe this is related to my tax settings. But `shipping_amount` (net amount) and `shipping_incl_tax` (gross amount) are looking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had an error in my reasoning. If an order is canceled, it is always completely canceled. So I can be sure that `shipping_incl_tax` is also completely canceled.